# Bibtex (apacite) problem - unwanted space between volume and number

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I am writing my thesis with LaTeX. I'm citing the used references with `apacite`. All in all it worked all perfectly. However I'm facing one problem:

In the bibliography I always have space between the *volume* and the *number* of an article.

So it looks like this:

*Mustermann, M. (2013). Title of the article. Journal of the article, **4 (2)**, 28-35.*

It, however, should look like this:

*Mustermann, M. (2013). Title of the article. Journal of the article, **4(2)**, 28-35.*

Here is my TeX file:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{apacite}


    \begin{document}


    \section{First Chapter}

    Any Text which is cited \cite{test}.     


        \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{apa}

\end{document}
```

And the related file is this:

```
@article{test,
  title={{Title of the article}},
  author={Mustermann, Max},
  journal={Journal of the article},
  volume={4},
  number={2},
  pages={28--35},
  year={2013}
}
```

I know it's not much, but my professor criticized it and I want to change it. I read, that I need to alter the .bst-File of `apacite`, but I have no idea in which way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, you do not even have to modify any `.bst` files, the relevant macro can be found in `apacite.sty`.

Add the following code to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
    \Bem{#1}%             journal
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
      \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
    \fi
    \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
    \else
      \unskip({#3})%      issue number
    \fi
    \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
    \else
      \unskip, {#4}%      pages
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatother
```

It is an exact copy of the `\APACjournalVolNumPages` from `apacite.sty` but for some reason the code does not work properly when executed by `apacite.sty`, it needs to be hooked in via `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  title={{Title of the article}},
  author={Mustermann, Max},
  journal={Journal of the article},
  volume={4},
  number={2},
  pages={28--35},
  year={2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
    \Bem{#1}%             journal
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
      \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
    \fi
    \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
    \else
      \unskip({#3})%      issue number
    \fi
    \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
    \else
      \unskip, {#4}%      pages
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Any Text which is cited \cite{test}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

without a space.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{%   \makeatletter` needs to be `\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{%` catcode changes do nothing in a macro argument. As written `\ifx\@empty...` compares `\@` with `e` so all the tests are false.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, thank you very much for pointing that out. Can you explain why hooking an exact copy of the macro from `apacite.sty` into `\AtBeginDocument{` makes the macro works as expected?

Comment: You restore the original definition overwriting the one from apacite/german.apc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ahh, thank you! Good to know.

Comment: I have the same problem, only I'm using a different document type and preamble (pasted below). I tried the MWE code above, and I got an error that reads: `! LaTeX Error: \APACjournalVolNumPages undefined`. Here's my preamble- I assume that the problem is that I'm calling a different package and/or class. Can anyone point me toward a way to modify the MWE code provided above for my situation?
  `\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,keeplastbox,man,donotrepeattitle,floatsintext]{apa6}`
`\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Comment: @Chris This solution will not work with `biblatex`. If you want an answer for your set-up with `biblatex`, please ask a new question with [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is a conflict between the DGP (Deutsche Gesellschaft fuer Psychologie/ German Association of Psychology) and APA. If you use the ngerman option in babel, the apacite-package is switching to the rules of the DGP. I had the same problem and fixed it this way (compare the issue number line for nongerman and german option):

```
%---- remove space between volume and issue of a journal ----
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \Bem{#1}%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
%    \unskip\ ({#3})%    issue number, with the added leading space
    \unskip({#3})%    issue number, without the added leading space
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {#4}%      pages
  \fi
}%
\makeatother
%---- end space correction ----
```

Answer (score 0):

Du bist mein Held!!!
Hat zwar ein bißchen gebraucht, bis ich die korrekte Stelle in den tex Files gefundne habe, wo ich das reinkopieren muss, aber jetzt klappts

PS: meiner Erfahrung nach muss man da auch gleich setzen.

\renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}

Damit der Beistrich vor dem vorletzten Autor im Litverzeich

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE! BTW, this is English speaking size :-)