# Extra space between volume and number using Biblatex and APA

Tags: biblatex, apa6

I am using biblatex as I write using the APA format. My professor noted formatting issues with my citations- there is a space between the volume and number that shouldn't be there: **12(2)** vs. **12 (2)**. For example, a citation should appear as:

`Lock, R. M. & Hazari, Z. (2016). Discussing underrepresentation as a means to facilitating female students’ physics identity development. Physical Review Physics Education Research, 12(2), 020101.`

What I'm getting right now is:
`Lock, R. M. & Hazari, Z. (2016). Discussing underrepresentation as a means to facilitating female students’ physics identity development. Physical Review Physics Education Research, 12 (2), 020101.`

This issue is similar to the one described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139004/bibtex-apacite-problem-unwanted-space-between-volume-and-number), but I am using biblatex so the solution there doesn't work for me.

MWE: (first line won't show as code if I use 4 spaces- maybe it's too long? Tried using 4 spaces... ended up with backticks)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,keeplastbox,man,donotrepeattitle,floatsintext]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\author{MyName}
\title{ThisPaper}
\addbibresource{My Library.bib}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Lock and Hazari argued that \citep{lock_discussing_2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Associated library file:

```
@article{lock_discussing_2016,
  title = {Discussing Underrepresentation as a Means to Facilitating Female Students' Physics Identity Development},
  volume = {12},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevPhysEducRes.12.020101},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevPhysEducRes.12.020101},
  timestamp = {2017-03-28T01:44:08Z},
  number = {2},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review Physics Education Research},
  author = {Lock, Robynne M. and Hazari, Zahra},
  date = {2016},
  pages = {020101},
  file = {wiped},
  groups = {wiped}
}
```

Screenshot: [image]
[pdf output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B79Q6nTY2RIgWVBkbmwxSG9nOTA)

Comment: With up to date `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` I do *not* get a space between the `volume` and `number`. Can you make sure to update all packages involved and try again. If the problem persists a screen shot would help.

Comment: moewe- thanks for the suggestion. Just updated all the packages in MiKTeX and I'm still having the issue. I'll add a screenshot and the pdf file.

Comment: There is *no* space in the screenshot and your PDF. I'm confused now. Do you want a space, or do you want no space?

Comment: There is a space even though it doesn't look like it's there. Highlight the text in the pdf and copy it into word (or any other editor) and it shows up more clearly. I do not want a space.

Comment: There is no space there. It might look a bit more space-y because of the italics (and italic correction!), but there definitely is no space. I checked with Sumatra PDF and got no space with copy and paste. If your editor has a space there that is because of its character mapping.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I checked using Sumatra and found the same thing you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no proper space there. There is, however, a bit of additional kerning known as italic correction ([What is the difference between \em and \emph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25911/35864), [How does italic correction work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93961/35864)). You can get rid of that with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{{\em\apanum{#1}}}
```

---

If you want use 'uncorrected `\emph`' more often, go with

```
\makeatletter
\protected\long\def\blx@imc@mkbibemphnc#1{%
  {\em#1}\blx@imc@setpunctfont\emph}
\blx@regimcs{\mkbibemphnc}
\makeatother
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibemphnc{\apanum{#1}}}
```

to define a version of `\mkbibemph` called `\mkbibemphnc` without italic correction.

Comment: moewe is correct- there was no space- just an artifact of the editor I was using to view the pdf. The code provided makes this more obvious.