# Natbib - Custom-bib - Merlin.mbs - Unwanted thin space between volume and num in reference list

Tags: natbib, custom-bib

I have a problem with the .bst file, I created with the help of custom-bib (make-bst). I needed to create an individual .bst file since the Journal (Journal of Intelligent Manufacturing) is using a little mixture of styles (some Harvard, some APA, some individual). So far so good, I had no problem with custom-bib or the dbj files and creating/adapting the .bst file.

BUT: I have a problem with the formatting of the Reference list - The problem is the thin-space between the volume and the number: "46 (32)"
Even if I use the default option for

"JOURNAL VOL AND NUMBER:"
`\beginoptiongroup{JOURNAL VOL AND NUMBER:}{}`
`\optdef{*}{}{Journal vol(num)}{as 34(2)}`

the result stays the same. I figured out that this is due to the different handling of textit, it, em, see examples in the "min example".
This behaviour is also nicely described in [Extra space between volume and number using Biblatex and APA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365701/extra-space-between-volume-and-number-using-biblatex-and-apa)
but unfortunately this solution only works for biblatex...

With the help of the merlin.pdf documentation I also found out that there are already options for this:

`\optdef{i}{em-it}{Use true italics}{ie, \string\it, absolute italics`
`\optdef{t}{plntx}{Use only Plain TeX}{commands for fonts and testing}`

See also the final options I am passing to the creation (except of adapted_style.dbj):

Processing file merlin.mbs (ay,nat,nm-rev,jnrlst,nmlm,x6,m1,keyxyr,dt-beg,yr-pa
r,note-yr,vol-it,volp-com,num-xser,bkpg-par,add-pub,edpar,bkedcap,pp,ed,xedn,an
d-xcom,xand,em-it,plntx,) -> adapted_style.bst

But still the same effect. Does anyone of you has a solution for this?

Yours sincerely, David

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{adapted_style}
\bibliography{sample.bib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={ }}

some text \cite{Ahmad2013}

See example:

\begin{itemize}
    \item with-space:{17} (18)
    \item textit:~\textit{17}(18)
    \item it:~~~~~\it{17}(18)
    \item em:~~~~~\em{17}(18)
    \item rm:~~~~~\rm{17}(18)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Content of sample.bib:

```
@article{Ahmad2013,
author = {Ahmad, Iftikhar and Kano, Manabu},
journal = {IFAC Proceedings Volumes},
number = {32},
pages = {744--749},
publisher = {IFAC},
title = {{Some interesting paper}},
volume = {46},
year = {2013}
}
```

adapted_style.dbj (creates "adapted_style.bst" with `latex adapted_style.dbj`" see in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CGrNs4g7)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like to answer my own question...BUT in case it is helpful for someone else, I post the solution for my own problem...

Found out that this was not a problem at all, since the behaviour when using vol-it and "" is working as intentioned, it is even mentioned in the ACTUAL documentation of merlin.mbs:

`\optdef{i}{vol-it}{Volume italic}{as {\string\em\space vol}(num)}`
so the original function for emphasizing stuff as it results by running the dbj file in order to create the .bst file looks like that:

```
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\it " swap$ * "\/}" * }
  if$
}
```

the "thin space" is added on purpose, and by deleting it, it is also gone in the reference list:

```
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\it " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

Yours sincerely, David

Comment: The `\/` isn't technically a normal thin space, it's the so-called italic correction that stops an italicised letter to bump into the following non-italic letter (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93961/35864). This is often desirable, but not always. Note that `\it` has been deprecated for more than 25 years now, so if you are already changing the definition of that function, you might as well replace `\it` with `\itshape`, see for example https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I will adapt it :-)